# How to do Encryption and Decryption in Cypress without revealing our actual credentials in any of the files in folder structure?

Tags: encryption, cypress

So, I wanna write a test script which has to pass some personal information like username and password to login the page, but I don't wanna reveal my actual credential in cypress console or to be included anywhere in my files in the folder structure since my code is accessible to multiple users in my team. Is there a way to do it? If anyone could help me with this?

I make use of `fixtures` and `support` folder to hold my credentials instead of directly included them in the `spec` file itself but still the folders and file is accessible by other members, so there is no meaning to do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the secret data in *any* file within the project will be problematic.

I would create a file to hold the secrets ***outside of the project*** (any folder on your disk) and obviously don't share that file.

For example, `/secrets/cypress-secrets.json`

```js
{
  "username": "my-name",
  "password": "123"
}
```

Then the `cypress.config.js` file will read this file and add it to the Cypress environment variables

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

const fs = require('fs')
const secrets = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../secrets/cypress-secrets.json', 'utf-8'))

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

    },
  },
  env: {
    ...secrets,                        
  },
})
```

And so in the test, just use `Cypress.env('username')`

```js
it('tests something with secret data', () = {
  const usename = Cypress.env('username')
  const password = Cypress.env('password')
  ...
})
```